# How to load appsettings.json inside a Static class based on deploy environment so that I can use in other class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, appsettings

W'm working on a migration project. I need to use my appsettings in other class libraries. so after googling and stackoverflowing, I load my appsettings.json inside static class as follows:

```cs
public static class ReadAppConfig
    {
        private static readonly IConfiguration Root;
        private static readonly ConfigurationBuilder ConfigurationBuilder;

        static ReadAppConfig()
        {
            if (ConfigurationBuilder == null)
            {
                ConfigurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                ConfigurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.QA.json", optional: true);
                ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Dev.json", optional: true);
                ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Staging.json", optional: true);

                if (Root == null)
                    Root = ConfigurationBuilder.Build();

            }
        }

        public static string UserManualFile => Root.GetSection("AppSettings:SomeKey").Value;
    }
```

So now I can get `UserManualFile` like `ReadAppConfig.UserManualFile` in other libraries.

This works fine. But it always reads from `appsettings.Staging.json` only. How to make this read based on deploy environment.

I cannot get `IHostingEnvironment` here as this is static class.

Please assist / suggest me with proper way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two problems here. First, don't use a static class. Configuration is designed to be dependency injected and dependency injection is fundamentally incompatible with statics. In truth, statics are almost always the wrong approach, dependency injection or not. Second, libraries should depend only on abstractions, not concrete data/implementations.

Honestly, there's three problems and the last one is the killer here: you need `IHostingEnvironment` for your use case, and there's absolutely know way to get that in a static class. Game over.

There's multiple ways you could go here, but I'm going to be opinionated with what I feel is the best option. Ultimately, your libraries just need `UserManualFile`, it seems. As such, that is *all* they should depend on: a string that corresponds to the location of a user manual, presumably. So, you'll do something like:

```
public class SomeLibraryClass
{
    private readonly string _userManualFie;

    public SomeLibraryClass(string userManualFile)
    {
        _userManualFile = userManualFile;
    }
}
```

This requires the least amount of knowledge and provides the greatest amount of abstraction for your library. It no longer cares where or how it gets the file location, just that it gets it.

Then, in your actual app, you'll use strongly-typed config to provide this value:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

...

services.AddScoped(p =>
{
    var appSettings = p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
    return new SomeLibraryClass(appSettings.Value.UserManualFile);
});
```

Done. Now, if there's actually other stuff the library needs, you might choose to pass a custom "settings" class to the library. This class should come from the library, so that it documents what it needs. For example, in your library, you'd create a class like:

```
public class SomeLibrarySettings
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Then, your library class(es) would inject this:

```
public SomeLibraryClass(SomeLibrarySettings settings)
```

Finally, in your app, you can either manually compose this settings class instance or inject it. Injecting it will still require you to manually compose it, so it only makes sense to do it that way if you're going to share it between multiple classes.

**Manually compose**

```
services.AddScoped(p =>
{
    var appSettings = p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
    var someLibrarySettings = new SomeLibrarySettings
    {
        Foo = appSettings.Value.Foo,
        Bar = appSettings.Value.Bar,
        // etc.
    };
    return SomeLibraryClass(someLibrarySettings);
});
```

**Inject**

```
services.AddSingleton(p =>
{
    var appSettings = p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
    return new SomeLibrarySettings
    {
        Foo = appSettings.Value.Foo,
        Bar = appSettings.Value.Bar,
        // etc.
    };
});

services.AddScoped<SomeLibraryClass1>();
services.AddScoped<SomeLibraryClass2>();
// etc.
```

Because `SomeLibrarySettings` is registered in the service collection, it will be automatically injected into the library classes that depend on it.

Finally, it's worth noting that because you're moving the configuration logic to where it actually belongs, you no longer need to even worry about the environment. ASP.NET Core is *already* set up to load the appropriate environment settings, so it just works.